# Can I get options of multi-select with selenium+python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

tested HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="html">html</option>
    <option value="css">css</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="php">php</option>
</select>
```

1. there's no method like `isMultiple()` under Class `selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select(webelement)`, also no `select_all()`method
2. when I select these 4 options one by one

```
Select(lang).select_by_visible_text("html")
Select(lang).select_by_visible_text("css")
Select(lang).select_by_visible_text("JavaScript")
Select(lang).select_by_visible_text("php")
```

and then try to get all selected options

```
Select(lang).all_selected_options
```

I can only get the last option 'php', which means when I select one option, the other one is deselected automatically. What's the meaning of `all_selected_options`, `options` is useful enough. And I can't deselect any option as there's only one selected, an error reported:

```
NotImplementedError: You may only deselect options of a multi-select
```

Comment: This dropdown doesn't seem to support multi select. Can you select more than one option manually?

Comment: Of course not. then ```all_selected_options``` and ```deselect_``` methods are all no use?

Comment: Just because this dropdown doesn't support multi select, it doesn't mean all the dropdowns doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select multiple options using selenium in python, you can always use `ActionChains` to chain series of action, we need following actions in our case:

1. Press `CTRL` key
2. `Click` on option
3. Release `CTRL` key

**Here is a good example of using ActionChains in python**

Make a list of options you want to select in python, loop through list and use `xpath` to select option containing the `text` and then use `ActionChains` to select the option using series of actions as defined above.

```
# Text of options needed to select
options = ['html','css','php']

# Add path to your chrome drive
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="EXECUTABLE_PATH_HERE")

# Add url of website
browser.get("WEBSITE_URL_HERE")

for option in options:
  # Find option that contains text equal to option
  to_select = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[text()='"+option+"']")

  # Use ActionChains
  ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(to_select).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

- `ActionChains()` get reference of driver that is `browser` in this case.
- `key_down()` press the key that is `CONTROL` passed to it.
- `click()` click the passed option that is selected using `xpath`.
- `key_up()` release `CONTROL` key

I hope this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This dropdown doesn't support multi selection, such dropdown will have `multiple` attribute

```
<select multiple="">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

There is no `is_multiple()` function, but there is a variable `is_multiple`. It's created in `Select` `__init__` by checking the `multiple` attribute

```
def __init__(self, webelement):
    self._el = webelement
    multi = self._el.get_attribute("multiple")
    self.is_multiple = multi and multi != "false"
```

You can access it using `Select` instance

```
Select(element).is_multiple
```

To get all the dropdown options regardless if they are selected use `option` property, this will return all the options as `WebElement` list

```
options = Select(element).options
for option in options:
    print option.text # html, css, ...
```

Comment: there's neither ```is_multiple()``` nor ```is_multiple``` under ```Select``` class. I checked in the selenium doc: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select

Comment: @elf It's not in the docs, but you can see it in the source code. Try to use it (without the `()`).

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared:

```
<select>
    <option value="html">html</option>
    <option value="css">css</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="php">php</option>
</select>
```

The `<select>` tag doesn't have the attribute **`multiple`**. So possibly it isn't a [multi-select](/questions/tagged/multi-select)[drop-down-menu](/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu).

---

To extract the *text* from the `<option>` tags you can use you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `tag_name`:

  ```
  select_technology = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))
  for option in select_technology.options:
      print(option.text)
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  select_technology = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(//select))
  for option in select_technology.options:
      print(option.text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
  ```